# how to store cookie when click on anchor

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am counting the clicks on anchors and store the number of clicks in a `.txt` file.
When click on an anchor, the number increases by 1.
I am not using a user management system, so to prevent multiple clicks on an anchor by a user, i need to store a cookie.
But i do have multiple anchors. If a user clicks on anchor 1, the number of click events on anchor 1 increases by 1. He should not have the possibility to click a second time on anchor 1, at least: it should not increase by 1 anymore.
But for that user, he still must be able to click on anchor 2 and anchor 3 and it should increase with 1. And after this, also these anchors should not increase by 1 anymore when user clicks on it.

How can i achieve this?

This is my html;

```
<?php
$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
$tmp = explode('||', $line);
$count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
}

?>

<a href="#count" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="count1">Like</a> 
<span class="click-count"><?php echo $count['count1'];?></span> likes.

<a href="#count" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="count2">Like</a> 
<span class="click-count"><?php echo $count['count2'];?></span> likes.

<a href="#count" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="count3">Like</a> 
<span class="click-count"><?php echo $count['count3'];?></span> likes.
```

The js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click-trigger', function()
{
   var data = {'id':$(this).attr('data-click-id')};
   var count = $(this).next(".click-count");


   $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : 'counter.php',
   data : data,
   success :  function(data)
       {                                                
            $(".click-count").fadeIn(500).show(function()
            {
                count.html(data);

            });                     
       }
   });
   return false;
 });
```

And this is file `counter.php`

```
$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
   $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
   $item = trim($line[0]);
   $num = trim($line[1]);
   if(!empty($item)){
     if($item == $id){
       $num++; // increment count by 1
       echo $num;

     }
     $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
   }
 } 
 file_put_contents($file, $lines);
 fclose($fh);
```

The file `counter.txt` looks like this:

```
count1||36
count2||124
count3||12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize` on an array of item numbers when setting the cookie value from php, and `unserialize` when reading the cookie. You will get an array of integers and can check with `in_array` whether the user has already clicked the link.